# How To Create and Use a Drop Down List With Reporting Services?

Tags: reporting-services

How do you create a drop down box on the report so the users can chose a value and conduct their search according to that value, See I have a SP that when the users enter a parameter they get the results according to that paramter, I would like for the choose one rather then type it up.

I have to give 2 dropdown boxes, from which users  can select a value,based on the selected value,(those parameters ) will be passed to execute a query and have to display a report.

Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the choices available to the end user using a query. To do this you need to right click on your parameter and go to properties. In the “Available Values” tab select “Get values from a query” you can then type a query that contains the options you want the user to be able to pick from. It will then present them as a normal dropdown list to the user